# Extjs Combo Box get previous value?

Tags: combobox, extjs4

Trying to get the previous value of the combo box. I tried 'change' event, but it does not work. 'beforeselect' does not exist for the new extjs 4.0 if i am not wrong. Any ideas on how i can do this?

I understand we can use the change event, but that only happens when the user types something. I want to check if there is an previous value on each new select?

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of weird that there is no `beforeselect` event. However, `combobox` extends `picker` and every picker has selectionModel with `beforeselect` event. So you may assign handler to picker selModel's `beforeselect` event:

```
MyCombo.getPicker().getSelectionModel()
    .on('beforeselect',function(sm, selections, i) {
        console.log(sm.lastSelected, selections, i);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the previous value of the combo from valueModels of the combo object in beforeselect event.

```
beforeselect: function(combo, record, index, eOpts){
    me.prevCountry = combo.valueModels[0].data.COUNTRY_ID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use change event handler that pass this params to your listener `( combo, newValue, oldValue )`